# How to access image file from other computer other than UNC?

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, network-protocols

I have PostGreSQL database on the other `computer(B)`, also, have images saved in 'My Documents' on that `computer(B)`. The information system software I created using Visual Studio 2012 deployed on my `computer(A)` gets information from the database on `computer(B)`.

How can I access the images from `computer(B)` because they are linked, by ID, on the records from the database?

**UPDATE** I have already solved the issue, shared the folder of images to `(A)`, and used [UNC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg465305.aspx) on my source codes. Is there any other way to make this possible? Will [NetBIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS) help me on this one?

Comment: you can use `VB.NET`'s `My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile` to get .jpg from one computer to another

Answer (score 0):

Share the folder from (B) to (A).

It looks like you're using Windows, so that's straightforward enough.

If the two machines aren't on the same local network you might well need to change your firewall settings to allow access. Allow just the IP address of machine (A).

Answer (score 0):

Unless the images themselves are stored in the database, you're not going to be able to read them from it.

If you have some form of web server running on `(B)` then you could feasibly write code to pull the image you want based on the database information and send it to `(A)` through that.